# Parse program output in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a program we use called HDClone, and I am trying to parse it's output from drive listings to use in another program for automation.

HDClone produces the following output:

```
HDClone 6 Enterprise Edition
Serial: 1111111111

Miray Software AG
Gaissacher Str. 18
81371 Munich
Germany

Detecting drives.
drv:0      Name: WDC WD40EZRZ-00WN9B0 (4,000,754 MB)
           Serial: WD-WCC4E0ESU7YK
           Port: 0/1/1/0
           [ -, M:, X: ]
To specify this drive, use the following parameters:
-srcdrv:/-dstdrv:0
-srcdrvn:/-dstdrvn:"WDC WD40EZRZ-00WN9B0"
-srcdrvn:/-dstdrvn:"WDC WD40EZRZ-00WN9B0WD-WCC4E0ESU7YK"
-srvdrvp:/-dstdrvp:0/1/1/0

drv:1      Name: ST2000DM001-1CH164 (2,000,399 MB)
           Serial: S1E1GA0V
           Port: 0/1/1/1
           [ S:, T: ]
To specify this drive, use the following parameters:
-srcdrv:/-dstdrv:1
-srcdrvn:/-dstdrvn:ST2000DM001-1CH164
-srcdrvn:/-dstdrvn:ST2000DM001-1CH164S1E1GA0V
-srvdrvp:/-dstdrvp:0/1/1/1

drv:2      Name: ST2000DM001-1CH164 (2,000,399 MB)
           Serial: S1E1GC0Z
           Port: 0/0/0/1
           [ B:, P: ]
To specify this drive, use the following parameters:
-srcdrv:/-dstdrv:2
-srcdrvn:/-dstdrvn:ST2000DM001-1CH164
-srcdrvn:/-dstdrvn:ST2000DM001-1CH164S1E1GC0Z
-srvdrvp:/-dstdrvp:0/0/0/1

drv:3      Name: WDC WD10EADS-11M2B2 (1,000,205 MB)
           Serial: WD-WCAV5D430071
           Port: 0/0/2/0
           [ -, V: ]
To specify this drive, use the following parameters:
-srcdrv:/-dstdrv:3
-srcdrvn:/-dstdrvn:"WDC WD10EADS-11M2B2"
-srcdrvn:/-dstdrvn:"WDC WD10EADS-11M2B2WD-WCAV5D430071"
-srvdrvp:/-dstdrvp:0/0/2/0

drv:4      Name: KINGSTON SMS200S360G (60,023 MB)
           Serial: 50026B72440A6EE7
           Port: 0/1/3/0
           [ C: ]
To specify this drive, use the following parameters:
-srcdrv:/-dstdrv:4
-srcdrvn:/-dstdrvn:"KINGSTON SMS200S360G"
-srcdrvn:/-dstdrvn:"KINGSTON SMS200S360G50026B72440A6EE7"
-srvdrvp:/-dstdrvp:0/1/3/0
```

What I need to produce is a listing like:

```
drv:0,[-,M:,X:]
drv:1,[S:,T:]
drv:2,[B:,P:]
drv:3,[-,V:]
drv:4,[C:]
```

Anyone have any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: There is alot consistant, but each drive has very individual details that I am not sure how to get around. Each has the Name:, Serial:, Port:, then the To Specify this Drive

Comment: That works for the first ones, but missed the last one. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Okay, I posted that as an answer, I think that will be stricter too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that format is consistent you should be able to run something like:

```
/^(drv:\d+)(?:[\s\S]+?(?:Name|Serial|Port):.*$){3}\n\h*(\[[^\]]+?])/m
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/eR0yK9/2

Comment: I like that is is strict, to make sure it is pulling only from the start, so we don't miss anything. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
(drv:\d+)[^[]+(\[[^]]+\])
```

It finds `drv:` followed by numbers and that is put into `$1`. Then it ignores everything up to a `[` and captures it and everything up to the `]`.

Your code might look something like this:

```
$re = "/(drv:\\d+)[^[]+(\\[[^]]+\\])/mi"; 
$str = "your string";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is one string try something like that (untested):

```
$output = [];
preg_match_all('#(drv:\d+)(^\[)+(\[(^\])+\])#ism', $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $output[] = $match[1].$match[3];
}
```

If not, combine it (e.g. implode) it beforehand.